# Why are the thread ids not unique?

Tags: c, multithreading

I am trying to create a thread for each file (targeting Linux). The number of files is based off of the number of files in the current directory.  Thus, I am trying to create a dynamic number of threads.

After reading many SO questions and answers about dynamic thread creation and additional research, I came up with the following code.  It is my understanding that to check if a thread was created for each file I can call gettid() which returns the caller's thread ID, and in a multithreaded process, all threads have the same PID, but each one has a unique TID.

However, the TID I am printing is not unique, and I am not understanding why.

```
char **filenames;
int file_cnt;
DIR *dir;


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int i;
    long tid;

    //atexit(cleanup);
    get_filenames();  //gets all files in the current directory

    printf("There are %d files:\n", file_cnt);
    pthread_t file[file_cnt];
    for(i = 0; i < file_cnt; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", filenames[i]);
        tid = syscall(SYS_gettid);
        pthread_create(&(file[i], NULL, get_filenames, (void *)file[i]);
        printf("%ld\n", tid);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Any suggestions as to why the threads are not unique? I am new to multithreading and am not understanding where I went wrong despite a lot of research.

Comment: Please read your question once more

Comment: I would add that creating one thread per file might lead to a lot of context switch contention, if the no. of files in the directory is >> no. of cores

Comment: You are only getting thread ID of the main thread, not of any additional thread you create.

Comment: @n.m. I see. Can you please explain how to get the thread id's of all threads? Also, can you please explain if I am actually creating multiple threads? Printing the tids was just a test of that.

Comment: Calling gettid inside get_filenames will get you unique thread IDs. Printing thrm correctly can be a bit tricky though. You need to mutex out the call to printf.

Comment: You're not creating multiple threads, because your code doesn't compile. Please, take the time and read a Pthreads tutorial and use `pthread_self()` to stay within that scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost non sense:

1. `gettid` returns the current thread id, so in your example the id of the thread created at the process creation. The for loop is executed by that thread, not any other one. `file[i]` is the thread id of the i-th created thread in your loop.
2. You created n threads that all executes the same `get_filenames` function. I suspect that this function return the same thing for all the n-threads that you already computed before the loop (I suspect because you didn't give us the code). And as it probably access the same `filenames` and `file_cnt` variables, you will probably have some serious concurrent access problem at some time...

The first point is the answer of your main explicit problem.

Don't use `syscall`, call the `gettid` function directly.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
 printf("%ld\n", tid);
```

should be

```
 printf("%ld\n", file[i]);
```

to print out the thread id of the newly created thread.

Also you should check that the thread has been created

Comment: `pthread_t` is not guaranteed to be an arithmetic type, much less `long int`.

Comment: The values are unique. So this means that I successfully created multiple, unique threads??